# Correlating two data sets in R leaving out subjects not in both

Tags: r, correlation

Still very new to R and have a question about performing a correlation. I have two data sets that I want to correlate. Let's say I named the sets Data1 and Data2 for simplicity. Most of the subjects are in both sets but there are some subjects that are not. This is a problem as I now have uneven data sets that cannot correlate. How do I tell R to ignore the subjects that are not in both data sets so that I can perform my correlation? I know there is likely a way to have R ignore these subjects in the same command where I ask it to correlate my sets.

Also if I want R to only correlate columns 4:7 using the subject IDs in column 1 would I, for example, use the command cor.test(Data1[1,4:7], Data2[1,4:7])?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: Have not test because no MWE provided.**

Try something like this:

```
cor.test(subset(x=Data1, subset=ID==1, select=4:7), subset(x=Data2, subset=ID==1, select=4:7))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

#### data

```
 dat1 <-  structure(list(V1 = c(9L, 2L, 5L, 9L, 9L), V2 = c(8L, 4L, 7L, 
 9L, 6L), V3 = c(4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 8L), V4 = c(7L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 1L
 ), V5 = c(9L, 2L, 10L, 7L, 10L), subject = 1:5), .Names = c("V1", 
 "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "subject"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

 dat2 <- structure(list(V1 = c(2L, 6L, 5L, 9L, 7L), V2 = c(2L, 10L, 5L, 
 5L, 6L), V3 = c(3L, 4L, 3L, 8L, 7L), V4 = c(3L, 2L, 10L, 1L, 
 9L), V5 = c(2L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 6L), subject = c(1, 3, 5, 6, 8)), .Names = c("V1", 
 "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "subject"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Create an index of subject IDs that are common in both

```
 indx <- intersect(dat1$subject, dat2$subject)
```

Apply `cor.test` on the dataset with common subject IDs

```
 cor.test(as.matrix(dat1[dat1$subject %in% indx,3:5]), as.matrix(dat2[dat2$subject %in% indx, 3:5]))
```